# How can make new line in input tag space?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make java script function that makes new line when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in  input tag space.

Also I hope, when making new line, the height of input tag space dynamically stretches.

```
<!-- onkeydown function -->
function Enter(){
   if(event.keyCode === 13){
      var element = document.getElementById("PostingArea");
      <!-- I don't know here -->
   }
}

<!-- html code -->
<input class="PostingArea" id="PostingArea" onkeydown="Enter()">
```

[image: Describe by photograph]

[image: like this]

Comment: use a `<textarea>` instead.

Comment: try my solution , it works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use textarea and indicate how many rows you expect, like this:

```
<textarea name="taText" cols="80" rows="25"></textarea>
```

Comment: I think textarea can't meet my requirements. When I press "Enter" key It can make new line. But, When I press "Enter" key when the cursor reaches the end of textarea space, it only makes a  scrollbar. It can't dynamically make the height longer..

Answer (score 0):

Use textarea tag.using textarea multiple line text can be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this updated version

```
     function onTestChange() {
        var key = window.event.keyCode;
        var el = document.getElementById("PostingArea");
          var height = el.offsetHeight;
        var newHeight = height + 20;
        var value = el.val();
        // If the user has pressed enter
        if (key === 13) {
            el.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
             var newValue = value + '<br/>';
                 el.val(newValue) 
      return false;
        }
    if (event.keyCode == 8) {
el.style.height = newHeight - 'px';
 var newValue = value - '<br/>';
                 el.val(newValue) 
return false;
    }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }



       <body>
    <div id ="PostingArea" class="input-area" style="height:20px;" onkeypress="onTestChange()">
        <input type="text" style="height:100%;" />
    </div>

        </body>
```

Comment: Thank you. It executes very well. But It can't dynamically make the height longer..

Comment: You mean the height of the newline for the textarea? or when they backspace it will reduce remove the /n?

Comment: I added photograph to describe more specifically. When I press "enter" key, It makes new line and increase textarea height. but press "backspace" key, It remove line and reduce textarea height.

Comment: can you test with this code . haven't tested. do give me feedback so i can assist.

Comment: Good work! But, It doesn't need. because it's textarea tag's basic functions. I want function to adjust textarea space height instead of scroll bar. So I want to use input tag instead of textarea. Because, textarea tag basically have scroll bar.

Comment: try this one @Mgeni

Comment: It succeeded in increasing the height of the input tag space! But It can't make new line. I tried (el.value += "\n*";) in if code. When I press enter key, PostingArea's value is changed, but It's not apply to input tag content.

Comment: An error occurred at (var value = el.val();). The codes don't have function val(). What's the code of val function?

Comment: @Mgeni Value is the configurable text/int whereby the parameter are configurable like adding a new space.. What i posted above was invoking the css style. I'm figuring out which method to use.